# harmonic algorithm for extending compressed bandwidth of audio file

Tags: fft, audio, compression, audio-processing

I just found this site and feel at home :)

I've been playin around with python and some compression ideas and was wondering if there's anything like what I am trying to figure out...

I've noticed that mp4's uploaded to instagram go from ~0 to 13100Hz and on Youtube from ~0 to ~14000Hz... which is OK, but what if there was an algorithm to extend or at least soften this highcut, by taking the amplitudes of the frequencies within the respective bandwidths and applying a harmonic function, (possibly with averaging/weights), to add in implied values to the currently non-existant values (i.e. the and additional bandwidth from 14,000 to 20,000Hz would be harmonically synthesized and still have realistic values.) It could be a plug-in or something.

Anyways, I'm going to check out the board some, and hope to hear some smart replies! thanks!

Comment: there *is* something called an [aural exciter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exciter_(effect)) that's sorta meant to do something like this.  it sorta splits the audio into low and high bands, and the **high** band goes through some simple non-linearity (maybe a square function and a cube function) to generate frequency components what previously were absent, then it's added back to the low band.

Comment: Hi Evan! Welcome to your home then, but unfortunately **audio** is not throughly covered here and I don't know if it could change in the future... Anyway nothing shall stop you from asking your questions though.

Comment: oh, forgot to mention.  welcome to **comp.dsp**.

Comment: oops, i meant the DSP stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

there is also [this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.dsp/_7rnXM2xiqI/_hmSzNizblEJ) in [this *comp.dsp* thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.dsp/_7rnXM2xiqI/_hmSzNizblEJ).

1. high-pass filter your input signal (keep the unmolested input around for later).  the cutoff frequency should be adjustable.  i would think a 2nd-order HPF with a Q approx= 0.707 (Butterworth) would be good enough.
2. square that HPF output,
3. add (maybe with an adjustable gain coefficient) that squared HPF back to the original input and output that audio sample.

see if that brightens up your day.

Comment: Cool thanks! Wow you guys were some intense debaters back in the day! I've played around with Aphex exciters for audio production, hadn't thought of it in this scenario. What I did not know was about the odd-valued harmonics - which seems to be more of a problem with analog bridge rectifiers. What your saying looks good. Just to clarify I'm not replacing or mixing with filtered values - I am synthesizing harmonics to create values which were lost during compression or do not belong to the file or signal. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Has been tried many times with varying degrees of success (or lack thereof).

These days most streaming services are fairly good: Spotify streams Ogg Vorbis at 302 kb/s. Apple Music streams HE-AAC at 256 kb/s. These are typically good up to about 16k or so.

Any stuff that's up there tends to not be harmonic, but it's typically wide band; created by transient events: attacks, percussion, cymbals, key clicks, etc. I'd think the best you can do is to get the average spectral shape right: extrapolating from the highest octave you have plus some spectral shaping filter.

Whether that's better or worse than doing nothing makes for an interesting listening experiment.